# How to Loop through local storage to match login inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, local-storage

I am making a small login system using local storage.
In my js I need some way to loop through the local storage to check if there is a match between the input form and json (username, password) in local storage.

Can I use a normal for loop ? jQuery .each?

Answer (score 1):

Use Key to iterate in local db

```
for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
    console.log(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)));
}
```

and for keys :

```
for (var key in localStorage){
   console.log(key)
}
```

Comment: `$('body').append()`? Use a `console.log()`.

Comment: Or key = localStorage.key(i);  
        alert(localStorage.getItem(key));

Comment: my localStorage for users is call 'users', so: for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.users.length; i++) ?

Comment: and i dont need to .parse the storage before doing the for loop?